# Story about punishing a criminal with death many times

Tags: story-identification

This story was in Omni magazine.  It concerns a convict given the death penalty.

Before he dies, his soul is transferred to a different body, which is also killed, etc.

Comment: A likely duplicate of [Short story about a dissident tortured and brought back to life multiple times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58941/short-story-about-a-dissident-tortured-and-brought-back-to-life-multiple-times/58944#58944).

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [A Thousand Deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Thousand_Deaths_(Card_short_story)) by Orson Scott Card?

It was originally published in the December 1978 issue of Omni magazine.

[image]

> In a future where the USSR has occupied America, playwright Jerry Crove is found guilty of knowing about the planned assassination of a Russian high official and not reporting it to the authorities. After he is convicted of this crime in court Jerry is supposed to confess and apologize on TV.
>
> Instead of confessing Jerry gives a speech on freedom in America. As a result he is sentenced to be put to death, but being civilized, the authorities will bring him back to life. He will be released when he apologizes convincingly.
>
> After he is put to death the first time he tries to do what they want but is unable to convince anyone of his sincerity. The Russians try killing him in a variety of gruesome ways but as time goes by he becomes used to being killed.

and the conclusion

> Eventually they are forced to give up and exile him to another planet with the other unrepentant. He realizes they are grouping the worst of the worst, and this will eventually be their downfall.